# Cross-browser video preload

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I found a way to preload a video partially until 20% before playing which seems to work quiet well on Firefox :

```
            window.addEventListener("load", function() {

            var video = document.createElement("video");
            video.setAttribute("preload", "auto");
            video.setAttribute("controls", "true");
            var mp4 = document.createElement("source");
            mp4.setAttribute("src", "https://archive.org/download/ElephantsDream/ed_1024_512kb.mp4");
            mp4.setAttribute("type", "video/mp4");
            var webm = document.createElement("source");
            webm.setAttribute("src", "https://archive.org/download/ElephantsDream/ed_1024.ogv");
            webm.setAttribute("type", "video/ogv");
            video.appendChild(mp4);
            video.appendChild(webm);
            document.body.appendChild(video);

            var v = document.querySelector("video");
            v.addEventListener("progress", function() {
                (function() {
                    if(v.readyState == 4) {
                       var buffer = v.buffered; 
                       var loaded = (buffer.end(0) / v.duration) * 100;
                       console.log(loaded);
                         if (buffer.length === 1) {
                            if (loaded >= 20) {
                                console.log("Vidéo chargée");
                                v.play();                                }
                            }
                       } 
                })();
            }); 
        });
```

Unhappily, on Chrome, the video must be played to be buffered.

There is a cross-browser code to preload a video ?

Comment: Can you provide how are you setting up your video tag element?

Comment: I created a video element then I added it into the document body

Comment: Any property? like, autoplay, preload , etc?

Comment: In any case it would be good some visual help for others if you paste the whole code.

Comment: preload with auto value and controls. I append sources to the video element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The video always will preload unless you set

```
video.setAttribute("preload", "none");
```

The differences between browsers depends of the implementation. According the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/video.html#concept-media-load-resource) within resource **fetch algorithm**

> User agents may decide to not download more content at any time, e.g. after buffering five minutes of a one hour media resource, while waiting for the user to decide whether to play the resource or not, or while waiting for user input in an interactive resource.

So, unfortunately is no enterely under your control since you set **[preload](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/)=auto.** If you want cross-browsing I'd play with the property

```
video.setAttribute("autoplay", "true|false")
video.setAttribute("preload", "metadata|auto")
```

A bit info about [preloading on html5](https://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2013/04/12/html5-video-preload/).

-- update ---

I post here the final solution for Chrome provided by the owner of the question he provided via pastebin. Kudos to **jadw**

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
   var video = document.createElement("video");
       video.setAttribute("preload", "auto");
       video.setAttribute("controls", "true");
       video.setAttribute("webkit-playsinline", "true");
       video.setAttribute("playsinline", "true");
       video.setAttribute("autoplay", "true");
       var mp4 = document.createElement("source");
       mp4.setAttribute("src",
       "https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/devstories.mp4");
       mp4.setAttribute("type", "video/mp4");
       video.appendChild(mp4);
        video.onloadstart  = function() {
          video.volume = 0;
          video.addEventListener("progress", progressLoad);
          video.pause();
        };
        var progressLoad = function(){
            console.log(video.readyState);
           (function() {
             if (video.readyState === 4) {
               var buffer = video.buffered;                        
               var loaded = (buffer.end(0) / video.duration) * 100;
               console.log(loaded);
               video.currentTime = loaded;
               if ((buffer.length === 2) || (loaded >= 20)) {
                 video.currentTime = 0;
                 video.removeEventListener("progress", progressLoad);
                 console.log("Video loaded");
                 document.body.appendChild(video);
                 video.play();  
               }
            }
       })();
     };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I wanted to play the video only if the video is preloaded at 20% (look at the code above) : on Firefox it works but on Chrome the behavior expected isn't the same than the result.

Comment: Again, I could go thought diverse kind of technics there are on StackOverflow, like, pre download via Ajax (which is basically download 100% of the video) , try to cheat the browser playing video and pausing automatically and so on (that does not work anymore on Chrome). But still, the browser is smart enough to don't download some % or the whole video as developer demand. Think on the effect that would cause on mobile browsing. You can play and mute the video, set a poster in the top and when you react the 20% reset the video and play it again.

Comment: I finally found an ultimate solution which works on Chrome and Firefox perfectly. But I can't post it because I post to much low-quality answers.

Comment: Post here I pastebin.js link and I'll edit my answer giving you the credits. Then others will see your solution.